# CentOS 7 Network Issue (No Incoming Connections)

Tags: centos, ssh, networking

I have a CentOS 7 server running on VirtualBox which seems to be running perfectly well except that I can't seem to be able to access it from another machine (ssh, apache or pings).

It was configured onto the network using the network interface (nmtui) to use the following static settings (selinux disabled)

```
GATEWAY : 192.168.1.1
IPADDR  : 192.168.1.88
DNS1    : 8.8.8.8
DNS2    : 8.8.4.4
```

It can access the internet fine.

I have a second CentOS 6 server running off the same VirtualBox with the same settings (except the IP is 192.168.1.87) and this one doesn't have any of the access problems. Both these VMs are using VirtualBox's Bridged Network Adapter.

If I run firewall-cmd --list-all I get the following

```
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: enp0s3
sources:
services: dhcpv6-client ssh
ports: 80/tcp
protocols:
masquerade: no
forward-ports:
sourceports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:
```

I'm not sure why this is, it doesn't seem to be related to VirtualBox as far as I can tell

*UPDATE*

It seems to be relate to the nmtui interface. If the nmtui is set to use automatic (DHCP) then everything works.

In order to set the Static IP I did the following

1. run nmtui
2. Edit a connection
3. Choose correct Ethernet Device
4. Edit

Then I gave it the following configurations

```
IPv4 CONFIGURATION <Manual>
Addresses 192.168.1.88
Gateway   192.168.1.1
DNS1      8.8.8.8
DNS2      8.8.4.4
```

From there it doesn't work, is there additional fields that are needed by nmtui?

Comment: Both the VMs are using Bridged Networks, they can access the internet, the CentOS 6 accepts incoming and outgoing but the CentOS 7 only accepts outgoing

Comment: Can you ping other machines on the network from the Centos 7 machine?

Comment: Yes pinging works, I can also SSH into the CentOS 6 machine from the CentOS 7 machine, just not the other way around

Comment: How about pinging/tracerouting from Centos 6 to Centos 7?

Comment: CentOS 6 can't ping CentOS 7, I'm not sure why

Comment: Try changing the MAC address on the virtual network settings for Centos 7

Comment: I've updated the question, it seems to be related to the nmtui interface

Comment: Change it manually in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts instead and restart the network service

Comment: It seemed just doing it without nmtui got it sorted, that's a bit disappointing though the nmtui seems really nice

Comment: They can be nice but are just a front end to do something you could more reliably do yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there is a way to do it correctly with the nmtui tool, if I figure it out I will add it here as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the easiest way to resolve this issue is to change the network script manually. My network script was updated as follows

```
# vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.88
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=*UUID GOES HERE*
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
ZONE=public

# systemctl restart network
```

Answer (score 0):

For DHCP configuration make sure following entries are there on the config file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

```
 BOOTPROTO=dhcp
 ONBOOT=yes
```

Above config update works for me